# django model fields comparison

Tags: django, django-models

is there a way l can compare two columns | fields in django  like

```
Invoice.objects.filter(amountdue_lt=invoiceamount)
```

where `amountdue` and `invoiceamount` are two columns of `Invoice` object

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, in Django 1.1 using the [F() object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#filters-can-reference-fields-on-the-model)